# r h2o.deeplearning: error when using weights - "weights_column" must be of type character, but got numeric

Tags: r, h2o

I've been trying to add data point weightings to my analyses with h2o.deeplearning.

The following code

```
library(h2o)
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- x-x^2+rnorm(1000,sd=0.2)
w <- vector(length=1000)      #weights vector
w[] <- 1
dfx <- data.frame(x,y,w)
h2o.init()
dfx <- as.h2o(dfx)

H <- h2o.deeplearning(x = 1, y = 2,training_frame=dfx,weights_column = 3, hidden=c(5,4))
```

gives

```
Error in .h2o.checkAndUnifyModelParameters(algo = algo, allParams = ALL_PARAMS,  : 
"weights_column" must be of type character, but got numeric.
```

Substituting the weights_column '3' for 'w' gives the same result. I tried as.character(w), but it definitely did not like that.

Substituting weights_column with dfx[,3] or dfx$w gives:

```
Error in args$x_ignore[!(weights_column == args$x_ignore)] : 
  invalid subscript type 'environment'
```

This error has left me scratching my head, as it appears to be different to how this sort of thing is implemented in any other model. I've found no references to this error by google, and the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/h2o/versions/3.22.1.1/topics/h2o.deeplearning) doesn't give any further explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved this embarrassingly quickly after submitting this question. Still it's worth keeping for others with similar problems.

The weights_column has to be specified by the *name* of the column in the h2o.data.frame. I.e. it has to be enclosed with quotation marks. It can't be a different h2o object or the index of the column. The following code works.

```
library(h2o)
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- x-x^2+rnorm(1000,sd=0.2)
w <- vector(length=1000) #weights vector
w[] <- 1
dfx <- data.frame(x,y,w)
h2o.init()
dfx <- as.h2o(dfx)


H <- h2o.deeplearning(x = 1, y = 2,training_frame=dfx,weights_column = "w", hidden=c(5,4))
```